# Excel 2010 hangs on launch even after removing both XLSTART folders

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel-2010, freeze

On Windows 7 Professional SP1 32-bit on a Lenovo Core i5 laptop with 2 GB RAM, Excel 2010 is suddenly hanging on launch. It opens fine in [safe mode](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/work-with-office-safe-modes-HP010354300.aspx#_Toc312758060). Office 2010 shows version 14.0.6029.1000.  Very little in terms of other installed software (Pidgin, Acrobat X Standard 10.1.4, Firefox).

Things I've tried:

- Disabled all add-ons (only real one was Acrobat) and removed both XLSTART folders
- Ran Windows Update and restarted
- Ran `Regsvr32.exe %Windir%\System32\Ole32.dll` as admin
- Ran the Repair function from the Add/Delete programs section of the Control Panel
- Uninstalled Excel 2010, restarted, reinstalled from the same installation media (SP1 ISO direct from Microsoft VLS)
- Uninstalled all of office 2010, restarted, reinstalled from same.

None of the above have worked. The real kicker is that Excel seems to be working perfectly when logged in via other AD accounts or as the local administrative user.

TIA.

Comment: You should [edit] your own question to add these extra details instead of adding comments. It makes the flow of the question easier to follow for readers.

Comment: It sounds like this is happening all the time. But to clarify, is this when you are opening a specific file or all the time? Any error messages in Event Viewer?

Comment: No error messages in Event Viewer; happened on all files.

Answer (score 0):

Try the "Repair" function instead of a complete uninstall/reinstall. Open Programs and Features in the Control Panel, highlight "Microsoft Office ... 2010" and click the "Change" button at the top of the listbox. When Office Setup loads, select the "Repair" option. If this does not work, you may need to do a more thorough uninstall and reinstall.

Comment: Did this, restarted, same result.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes its hard to remember to see the forest when you're only thinking about the trees.

The user had kicked the power cord to his external monitor; the laptop was displaying the default Book1 empty Excel file on what would've been the external display.  Since there was still a VGA connection, despite the monitor being powered off, Windows was still in extended desktop.

*epicfacepalm*